# How to find out whether any part of an NSWindow is currently visible (not just ordered in)

Tags: macos, cocoa, custom-controls, nswindow

I have an NSWindow that is updated every second to display the current time.

This drawing is quite processor intensive and I want to avoid doing it while the window is **completely** obscured by other windows.

Unfortunately, [NSWindow isVisible] does not show whether a window is actually visible on the screen, but only whether it is **on screen** at the moment. Meaning if the window is in the window list but completely obscured by other windows isVisible == YES, my custom drawRect gets called and I end up drawing everything into a buffer that is never used.

Is there any way of detecting whether a Window and its content is **actually** visible on the screen?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On 10.9 you can use NSWindow's -occlusionState and the associated delegate method.

From the release notes:

> Windows are considered occluded if their entire content, including title bar and tool bar, is 100% covered by another opaque window. Windows are also occluded if they are ordered off screen, minimized to the dock, or on another space. Partial occlusion counts as “visible.”

Example:

```
- (void)windowDidChangeOcclusionState:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ([[notification object] occlusionState]  &  NSWindowOcclusionStateVisible) {
        // visible
    } else {
        // occluded
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did see that in the API changes.. funny how long it took to get that API in there :-)